# How can I correctly use MPI_Reduce function?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am new in c++ and also MPI, so I have some problems.

In my code, process 0 reads text files (burcu - name file, alphabet -all letters in alphabet) and convert the name file into an array of numbers. By MPI_Bcast, I distribute the numbers of letters to different processes, and these slave processes make some arithmetical operations. At the end, by using MPI_Reduce, I collect the result of these arithmetical operations (which is xnum) into the weightednum at process 0.

The problem is when I run the code, although xnum values are correct, weightednum has a weird result like 939605 (it shouldbe 215, which is summation of xnum's). What can be the reason of this incorrect result? My code is like following:

```
int main (int  argc, char **argv) {

int myid, nprocs;
int *countname, xnum, weightednum;
char *burcu, *alfabe;

MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
int size = 5;
countname = new int[size];
burcu = new char[5];
alfabe = new char[26];

char name[5];
char alphabet[26];


MPI_Reduce(&xnum, &weightednum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (myid == 0) {

    cout << "wn" << weightednum ;

    // Read myname.txt file and convert it to a string

    ifstream input("myname.txt");
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){

        input >> name;
        cout << name;
        burcu[i] = *name;   
    }


    // Read alhabet.txt file and convert it to a string


    ifstream input1("alphabet.txt");

    for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++){

        input1 >> alphabet;
        cout << alphabet;
        alfabe[i] = *alphabet;  
    }

     for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){ 

        for (int j = 1; j<= 26; j++){

            if (alfabe[j] == burcu[i]){

                countname[i] = j;
                break;
            } 

        }

        cout << countname[i] << " ";        
    }

    input.close();
    input1.close();



}

    // Send name and alphabet strings to all processors by means of broadcasting

    MPI_Bcast(countname, 6, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

if (myid != 0){

    // All processors receive the same messages, and they will take only one letter of your name

    //xnum = myid;
    xnum = countname[myid]*myid; 
    cout << "xnum:" << xnum;        
}


MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are calling `MPI_Reduce(&xnum, &weightednum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` before anything is read, is that correct?

Comment: At the beginning I have put it immediately before MPI_Finalize in order to enable it to read the files and make necessary calculations, but again I have obtained a value which is weird. This version was a trial actually, but when I put MPI_Reduce after all these calculations, still I have the same problem, does not matter the location.

Comment: `xnum` is not initialized on rank 0. ‘countname` has size 5 but you broadcast 6 elements.

Comment: When I initialize xnum at process 0, then it gives an error like "xnum is not declared in this scope". Also, the reason of writing 6 instead of 5 in Bcast is wher I wrote 5, it gives 0 to 5th process, i.e., it could not send the last value.

Comment: In `C` index starts at `0` ... so there is already a buffer overflow when accessing `burcu`, you’d rather fix that instead of adding yet an other overflow with `countname`. `xnum` is a local variable of `main` so there is no scoping issue. Please fix and edit the code, so we all talk about the same thing.